# In ASP.NET MVC 3, how can I apply an IAuthorizationFilter to all Controllers in a particular Area?

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

How can I apply an IAuthorizationFilter to all Controllers in a particular Area?

Inside the `OnAuthorization` method I tried to get access to the Area through the `filterContext` argument but I couldn't.

Is there a built-in way to set an Authorization Filter to all controllers in an Area? If not, how can I test the Area inside the `OnAuthorization` method?

Answer (score 0):

The [FluentFilters](https://fluentfilters.codeplex.com/) library allows you to apply filters to a particular area:

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        [...]
        FilterProviders.Providers.Add(FluentFiltersBuider.Filters);
        RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters, FluentFiltersBuider.Filters);
        [...]
    }


    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters,
                                             FluentFilterCollection fluentFilters)
    {
        fluentFilters.Add<AuthorizeAttribute>(
            c => c.Require(new AreaFilterCriteria("Admin")));
    }
}
```

The library gets the name of the area like this:

```
filterContext.RouteData.DataTokens["area"]
```